# loading list of nearby places iOS 7 using simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mapkit

I am using MapKit and I'm trying to retrieve a list of nearby places based on the users current location and after that, I am trying to display them in a TableView. However, when using the iOS simulator, no places show up. I went to simulator->debug->location->Apple so shouldn't results pertaining to THAT location show up? I'm confused. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[self CurrentLocationIdentifier];
    [self performSearch];
    _m= [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _places.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"placeCell";
    PlaceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    long row = [indexPath row];

    cell.placeLabel.text = _places[row];





    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int rowNo = indexPath.row;

    _place = [_places objectAtIndex:rowNo];



}


- (void) performSearch {
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request =
    [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _m.name;

    _places = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    MKLocalSearch *search =
    [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse
                                         *response, NSError *error) {
        if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
            NSLog(@"No Matches");
        else
            for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
            {
                NSString *n = item.name;
                [_places addObject:n];


            }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the search completion handler called? What happens? You don't provide any useful information about the code you posted.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Nothing happens when it is called (it is called in viewDidLoad). the UITableView is empty.

Comment: You need to clarify. When you debug the code, is `performSearch` called? If so, is the `startWithCompletionHandler:` method called? If so, is the completion block ever called? Details. You need to provide details. We are not psychic. Tells us what happens exactly.

Comment: the handler is called, the log says "No Matches", but I'm wondering why that is...shouldn't it at the least show a few results that are close to the current location? In this case, whatever "Apple" is

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bunch of log statements and look at what is displayed in the console (or add breakpoints and use the debugger, but I'm guessing you don't know how to do that.

Add a log statement at the beginning of your performSearch that displays the _m.name that you are using as your search string. Add a log to the top of your completion handler so you know that it's called.

Comment: the handler is called, the log says "No Matches", but I'm wondering why that is...shouldn't it at the least show a few results that are close to the current location? In this case, whatever "Apple" is

Comment: I don't know, what are you searching for? Have you tried using the same search from the Maps application, with the location set to the same place?

Comment: Ok, the log is now showing the wanted results, but the results are not showing up in the tableviewcontroller

Comment: Oh lordy. The docs are a good thing you know. How about calling `[myTableView reloadData]` (where you replace "myTableView" with the name of your table view.)

Comment: So either accept my answer or post your own answer with the solution and accept THAT, so the correct answer is on record, and people don't waste time trying to solve a problem that's already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for some reason the results started appearing after I changed the type of "row" in cellForRowAtIndexPath from long to int and instead of [indexPath row], I changed it to indexPath.row